# How to add nq-slider attribute directive to an element which has ng-model in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use a chat from angular based [Quantumui](http://quantumui.org/appdoc/documents/quantumui/aside/) module in my project and I don't completely understand what notice means.

**Just add nq-slider attribute directive to an element which has ng-model.**

Who can provide an example how could this relation looked like?

Answer (score 1):

You have to write something like this:

```
<div nq-slider ng-model="something">
```